# Setting the value of a textbox to a user entered value

Tags: textbox

How can I set the value of a textbox to user entered value.
For ex

```
    <input type = "text" name = "somename" value = "">
```

If the user enters "3" then it should become

```
    <input type = "text" name = "somename" value = "3">
```

All I want is that when I process the textbox for value in a servlet, I should be able to get the value 3 for that textbox. well, there is more to it as David says. The textbox is part of a cart application and it denotes quantity of an item. What I want to do is to be able to take the value of any item and store it in the database. I will have a default value of 1 for every textbox. But when I POST the data, I want it to post the value entered by the user and not the default value

Comment: I get the feeling there's more to this.  When a user enters a value into a textbox, that value is included in a POST to a server by default.  How are you accessing the value on the server-side?

Comment: Are you using a server side script or client side, to submit the elements?

Comment: I am POSTing the data to a servlet. This textbox is in a JSP

Comment: see my answer.  The default value is not transferred, the text in the box is transferred.  The `value` attribute only provides a default to be present when the element initially loads on the page.

Comment: @rockerest Thanks. To know that helps. I dont have to do much then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in the textbox is automatically transferred to the server when you submit the form as `somename=3` (or whatever value).

However, if you want to actually update the `value` attribute of the element, you could use jQuery to do something like:

### HTML

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="somename" value="">
```

### jQuery

```
$('#name').change(function(){
    $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());
});
```

### Javascript

*(untested, but might work if you don't want to use jQuery)*

```
<input type="text" name="somename" value="" onchange="this.attributes['value'] = this.value;">
```

Comment: can I use plain JAVAscript to do this? I will have "n" number of textboxes with default value 1 depending upon the number of items the user adds to the cart.